# Python - Turtle.onkey() - A way to accept Any/Unknown Key?

Tags: python, events, keyboard-events, python-turtle

I would like to build a little typing/keyboard demo of the turtles key event. I would also like to avoid having a separate onkey call and function for every single key on the keyboard.

Is there a way to Get the key pressed from the onkey event without separate events for each key?

Something like:

```
def getKey(key):
  turtle.write(key)

turtle.onkey(getKey,None)
turtle.listen()
```

Possible?

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62807747/5771269) does just this by making turtle's key event more like tkinter's upon which it sits.  It will extract the character typed from the event object and pass that to your function.  The default behavior seems a flaw in turtle given the `None` case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see it is not possible using Turtles alone. You can use the same handler for all keypresses by passing '' to `onKey`

```
def getKey():
  turtle.write('Key pressed')

turtle.onkey(getKey,'')
turtle.listen()
```

You may be able to use a different library such as [Getch](https://pypi.org/project/getch/) within the `getKey()` function to see which key if being pressed at the time.